# Need media sharing web-app, control access by group

Tags: web-applications, video, audio, media, flash

I am trying to find a good media sharing web app.  Something that will let instructors upload audio or video files easily. And I need to let restrict access to the files to only  the students in the class.

I have tried PHPMotion, and it's great for the uploading and sharing part, but it's a way of sharing files with everyone.  I need to restrict access by groups.

This is my wish-list:

> Web based.
>
> Open source or inexpensive
>
> LAMP
>
> Flash player.
>
> Automatic conversion to FLV
>
> Easy to use for non-technical people to upload files (people for whom FTP is too complicated)
>
> Accommodate streaming large media
>   files, not live streaming but letting the
>   user jump to the middle without
>   having to download the whole file.
>
> Ability to limit access by group.
>
> Allow download of media onto portable
>   devices.
>
> LDAP authentication
>
> Easy HTML embedding of player

I know I want everything.

PHPMotion is the closest thing I have found so far.  It's easy to upload and does conversion to FLV. I suppose I could hack it with some access controls, but I'd rather not.

Is anyone aware of a flavor of wiki that could handle media file sharing using groups?

thanks

Comment: From: http://phpmotion.com/content/view/17/33/

**Groups**
   
  - Create a new group for even more video sharing
  - Group admin can make group private or public
  - Videos can be deleted and added to the group very easily
  - Group admin can deleted members and also comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMotion was probably the closest thing I could find.

In the end we went with Adobe Flash Media Server and we'll write our own access controls.

Answer (score 0):

.

You did forget "256 bit Encryption"  :) :) :)

Not shure if you know that at Youtube you can have:

"private" mode.
"unlisted" mode.

or both

There´s also a way to have them upload
to/trough your website (to Youtube) without the need for them to go to Youtube itself.
cant remember the right terminology for that...check the Youtube-developers and api pages.

Youtube will meet most of your other requirements.

I see you choose Flash...for your knowledge iPhones, iPads dont do Flash
so you will need at least one more format also. 
Youtube does both Flash and Html5 it will create (online/automatically) up to 6 versions 
of your video for you and serve the right one depending on a visitors browser or device.

.